# Why does this Javascript not recognise the mouse up?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following Javascript code. If inside the div you press the middle and right mouse button down at the same time them move outside the browser with both buttons still pressed you then release one of them. This is recognized. But if you release the other this is not recognized. Is there either a way of recognizing the release of the second mouse button or alternatively when the mouse is moved back into the browser window to be able to find out what buttons are up/down so the state can be updated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div style="height:250px;background-color: pink"> </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var doc = $(document);
        var buttons = [ false, false, false ];
        function mouseDown(e) {
            buttons[e.which - 1] = true;
            console.log(buttons);
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        function mouseUp(e) {
            buttons[e.which - 1] = false;
            console.log(buttons);
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        doc.on("mousedown", mouseDown);
        doc.on("mouseup", mouseUp);
        </script>
    </body>  
</html>
```

**EDIT**

The code is [here](http://edheal.batcave.net/)

**EDIT 2**

Alternatively does anybody know why this is not possible and any references that state that this is not possible.

Comment: @George - I have tried adding `doc.on('blur')` without any success

Comment: I can't imagine a real world use for what you're trying to do... As others have already said once you let go of one mouse button outside of the browser it loses focus. Can't you just do `doc.on("mouseout", <FUNCTION>)` to cancel whatever operation was being performed?

Comment: @Pot-Nut - The problem is the the status of the mouse buttons gets out of sync with reality. When re-entering the browser the JS thinks that one of the mouse buttons is down and it may not be.

Comment: Yes, because while both mouse buttons are pressed the browser retains focus. Releasing one of the buttons outside the browser forces it to lose focus. The same happens when you use the right mouse button. Release  this first (prompting the menu), even inside the  browser, and it no longer recognises releasing the other button. It is impossible to do what you're asking. Best solution is to force mouseup state on `doc.on("mouseout"...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the document's `mouseenter` and event's `buttons` property to figure out which button is down when you re-enter the document:

```
doc.on("mouseenter", function(e) { 
    console.log("mouseenter: " + e.target + " buttons: " + e.buttons);
   //if (Object.prototype.toString.call(e.target) == '[object HTMLHtmlElement]') {
        if (e.buttons == 1){
             //left button
        }
        if (e.buttons == 2){
             //right button
        }
        if (e.buttons == 4){
             //middle
        }
    }
});
```

See [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent.buttons) for `buttons` property of the mouse events.

Update:

Link above: `A number representing one or more buttons. For more than one button pressed, the values are combined.` so

```
if (e.buttons == 1){
    //left button
}
else if (e.buttons == 2){
    //right button
}
else if (e.buttons == 4){
    //middle
}
else if (e.buttons == 3){
    //left and right
}
else if (e.buttons == 6){
    //middle and right
}
else if (e.buttons == 7){
    //all 3
}
```

**Update 2:**

The reason 2nd mouse up isn't registered is because after 1st mouse up, browser stops listening to mousemove events. Try your scenario in the question with these handlers below. mouse move will keep triggerring until you let go the 1st button. As soon as you release the first button, move doesn't get triggered anymore. I thought I could use `setCapture` or `focus` on mouse up to make the window continue watching the mouse but it doesn't work.

```
window.addEventListener("mouseup", function( event ) {
      console.log("window mouse up");
      //window.focus();
      //event.target.setCapture(true);
  }, false);

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function( event ) {
      console.log("window mouse move");
  }, false);
```

Comment: How about multiple buttons are down?

Comment: @EdHeal Sort of found out why it doesn't work but no solution. Can't find it in a document either. See 2nd update.

Comment: I give you the bounty even though it is not exactly the answer

Answer (score 2):

Back to the w3c spec for mouseup event (http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-mouseup):

1/ "A user agent must dispatch this event when a pointing device button is released over an element."

2/ **Authoring Note**: In some implementation environments, such as a browser, a mouseup event can be dispatched even if the pointing device has left the boundary of the user agent, e.g., if the user began a drag operation with a mouse button pressed.

Conclusion: The mouseup event that you may catch is triggered only to allow a drop outside the window. And because 1 pointer = maximum 1 drop, there are no reason that you can ever catch another event, as long as you have only 1 pointer.

For your problem: You have no way to know which button is pressed when the pointer comes back into the document, you must consider that both buttons are up by defaut, and as soon as you got the mouseup event at your document level.

Comment: Made a correction to the post - guess Halloween got to you :-)

Comment: We read the document. It is vague on this case. Guess we need to fix the browser

Comment: Thanks for the typo fix ^^.Indeed it's not really in the spec. But I think the browser is behaving correctly, it considers "mouseup out of window" as a "drop", and with a mouse you can't do a "double-drop", so it just doesn't trigger it, it fall's back to the spec: a mouseup needs a DomElement.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like that

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var doc = $(document);
    var buttons = [ false, false, false ];
    function mouseDown(e) {
        buttons[e.which - 1] = true;
        console.log(buttons);
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("down")
    }

    function mouseUp(e) {
        buttons[e.which - 1] = false;
        console.log(buttons);
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("up")
    }

    doc.on("mousedown", mouseDown);
    doc.on("mouseup", mouseUp);
```

});

Comment: Actually he is right. You need to wait for the document to fully load before attaching an event handler.

Comment: The example code the event handlers are getting called. Including the mouse up one. But only once for the first mouse button coming up and not the second

Answer (score 0):

in that moment, your mouse leaves the browser and you release on of the buttons, the browser will lose the focus. this is caused by the os. the browser needs to be focused to fire events.
I dont exactly know what you want to do when the keys are released, but maybe you can try out `$(window).on('blur')`, because i learned, that it is a big difference between body events, window events and document events. also the mouseup events are fired to that target, your mouse is targeting while releasing the button

Comment: I understand that but how do I get the second mouse up event? Any code?

Comment: There is no way to get the second event. Maybe if you can check on a window focus event which keys are pressed... but when you focus the windo, then you have to press a keys so the state would be wrong

Comment: @Mphiztopeles - Where in the standard or elsewhere does it say this?

Comment: in the standard? what do you mean?

Comment: In the standard for DOM as given in another answer. I am looking for a definitive answer in to why it is behaving the way it is (is the implementation of the browser correct?!)

Comment: your code is right, if you mean that... but... maybe im not as good in english as you, because i dont think i know what you want :D the browser doesnt reacto to a mouseup when the cursor is not in the browser. because then the os events will fire. a bit like the alert(). the alert stops all js output. i dont know if the browser looses focus on an alert but defenetly the js output stops :) maybe you can explain me in an easier way, what you expect me to answer.. or  whatever you want. please dont be angry about this :)

Comment: The browser receives the two mouse down events. Outside the browser it only gets the one mouse up event - not two as the second mouse down event occured withing the browser. If this is not possible then where does it say this? If it is possible them how. Please use the web page and verify by carrying out the steps.

Comment: Here you have some "discussion" about this of firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=566671  right now i've got an idea... what if you bind another event to the browser... blur.. and focus the window, if it loses focus.. maybe this will help... unbind the blur event on mouseup event to give the user a chance to activate other programs

Comment: I would like both mouse events to go to the javascript. Not just the one

Comment: ya, i know that... but as i said.. right that moment one button is released, the browser loses focus, so the second cant be listened. did you try my thoughts in the last comment above?

Answer (score -2):

The mouseup event is relative to where the pointer is and this is expected behaviour. If you want your button to style properly, bind the mouseleave event as well.